# Why does passing a function to a thread using make_unique<> cause a memory leak in Valgrind?

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, c++14

I'm trying to do this:

```
int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> up(nullptr);
    up = std::make_unique<std::thread>(upload, url, path);
    return 0;
}
```

where, `upload` is basically a static non-member function and `url` and `path` are `std::string`. `upload` is defined as:

```
static void upload(const string url, const string path){ int sync_status;}
```

But this is always getting reported as a memory leak under Valgrind:

```
249 (80 direct, 169 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 151 of 169
==12088==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12088==    by 0x1395F9: _S_make_state<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> , std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > (thread:197)
==12088==    by 0x1395F9: thread<void (&)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> &> (thread:126)
==12088==    by 0x1395F9: std::_MakeUniq<std::thread>::__single_object std::make_unique<std::thread, void (&)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> ), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(void (&)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> &, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (unique_ptr.h:825)
==12088==    by 0x131D8D: main
```

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The issue is there on my system @MaximEgorushkin. Are you not able to reproduce this?

Comment: You must post complete code that can be compiled and run. The 3 lines you posted do not compile.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry I'll improve it. Thanks @MaximEgorushkin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code ends up invoking [`std::thread::~thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) which calls `std::terminate` because the thread is neither detached nor joined. This is why `valgrind` reports an error.

Either join or detach the thread.